# will hash(time.time()) always be unique

Tags: python, time, hash

I am trying to generate unique ID **numbers** for some unit tests, and I saw a suggestion somewhere to use something like:

```
def unique_id():
    time.sleep(0.000001) # smallest precision for time.time()
    return time.time()
```

I'm wondering if the hash() call will always take at least 0.000001, so I could use:

```
def unique_id():
    return hash(time.time())
```

Could that ever return the same value twice, if I'm calling it in succession within a single threaded application?

edit: bolded the word 'NUMBERS' because every single person has overlooked it.

Comment: unless the time is exactly the same, no. `time.time()` returns an always increasing float so you should be safe.

Comment: Why not just use the UUID class instead of making your own?

Comment: See my response to Evan Fosmark for why a UUID wouldn't work for this.

Comment: According to that comment, you have "I'm dealing with many db fields". Wait, you have a database? Why aren't you grabbing the auto-increment integer from out of the database? The entire point of a "Primary Key / Autoincrement Integer" is to solve this exact problem! A proper insertion (with a properly designed database) is your best solution. Another solution is to create a Unique Index at the database level.

Comment: The "IDs" in question aren't the primary keys. As an example, I want to generate a random object of a certain type. I have a function which will generate the base data for the object, and rely on the insert into the database to generate the PK. But there is also, for example, a field called 'obj_name', which has a unique index. When that object generator is called, I need to generate a unique value for any fields that can't use the base data, so currently i am doing "name %x" % (time.time() * 1e6) after a time.sleep(0.000001).

This is working, but I thought I'd try to simplify it.

Comment: The methodology you're using doesn't really matter then. The important bit is to have logic that detects when an insert fails due to the Unique index test failing, and then to retry with a new value. That combined with any source of data (even just... plain-old time() calls) would be sufficient for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial to answer from the Python prompt:

```
>>> import time; print hash(time.time()) == hash(time.time())
True
```

(If you see `False`, you merely got really lucky.)

So, yes. Modern computers are easily fast enough to hash a float in under 0.000001 seconds. In fact, when I wrote that as a `while` loop that incremented a counter, it appears that on my machine, Python can get the time and hash it more than 5000 times in a row without seeing a difference. Not surprising: the hash is used for fitting objects into a hash table (dictionary), so one of its primary requirements is *speed.*

In any case, there is no requirement or guarantee that `hash()` return a unique identifier for each object. Two distinct values of `time.time()` (or any type) could have the same hash, and there is nothing preventing these two values from being "adjacent" by some definition.

What you want, as others have pointed out, is a UUID. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you can't use a UUID, use something that can't ever be duplicated, such as a counter.

Comment: I tested this before even posting, using the same sample line you posted, but never once saw equal values. I wasn't sure if a faster machine would have different results, that's why I asked.

Also, "5000 times per second" is still greater than the .000001 time difference than would yield a different value, so if it's 5000 times per second without seeing a difference, then the hashing process is still taking long enough to force the resulting time to be unique, right?

Comment: The "5000 times a second" was an error, it was really testing 5000 consecutive times. The whole script, which tested 1000 iterations of a while loop that looped until it saw a different hash, ran in under 4.5 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a unique value, it's recommended to use the [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) library.
Example:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('514c2bd7-75a3-4541-9075-d66560f42b5c')
>>> str(uuid.uuid4())
'6faad714-c2df-448b-b072-f91deb380e84'
```

If you need number-only values, use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) library.

```
>>> import random
>>> INT_MAX = sys.maxint #  Set INT_MAX to the max value for your given INT column
>>> random.randint(0, INT_MAX)
5188925271790705047
```

Comment: I'm dealing with many db fields which all have varying limitations on them. a UUID will not work, for example, in an INTEGER field, or a field limited to 16 characters.

Comment: For a field limited to 16 characters, just get a slice of the UUID.  For an integer field, why not use the `random` library?

Comment: Some test cases are against remote APIs that do not offer the ability to clear old records. By making it time-based, I am trying to avoid the possibility of conflicts with results of previous runs of the test suite.

Comment: Using part of a UUID is bad, all bytes in a UUID do not have equal randomness.

Comment: @GeraldThibault once you hash a time all concept of time and temporal ordering are lost.

Comment: Good point about slicing UUID, zaph. If I could edit my comment I'd remove that suggestion. I'd stick to looking at the `random` library, @GeraldThibault. That's what the library is there for.

Comment: @GeraldThibault: `int(uuid.uuid4())` works if you need an integer. `os.urandom(16)` gets you 16 random bytes. You should **edit your question** and add any restrictions relevant to your case there e.g., you shouldn't use the default random number generator such as used by  `random.randint()` in security related code (passwords, auth, etc), you could use `random.SystemRandom()` instead. And in reverse, in computer simulations where the time performance and statistical properties may be more important then security issues, you might make the opposite choice.

Answer (score 1):

Evan Fosmark already covered it.

But I want to add that Python's "hash" function is only 32-bits or 64-bits as far as I can tell. I don't even know how its implemented, but I doubt it is cryptographically random. Collisions are expected from the low-quality hash function.